# matching two words in a javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a url string that looks like the `https://www.bla.com/?test=dfsdf`
I want to try and match if **www.bla.com** and **?** is in the url.

The url should only match if its got www.bla.com/? or www.bla.com?

it should not match is its anything else follows like www.bla.com/test/?

First try was.

```
regex = /bla.com\?/g
```

Comment: You just need to match `www.bla.com` followed by optional `/` followed by `?`

Comment: Do you know how to match an optional character?

Comment: So an exact match starting with? `/^https:\/\/www\.bla\.com\/\?/`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`www\.bla\.com\/?\?`

https://regex101.com/r/tcUDdq/1

> www matches the characters www literally (case sensitive)
>
> . matches the character . literally (case sensitive)
>
> bla matches the characters bla literally (case sensitive)
>
> . matches the character . literally (case sensitive)
>
> com matches the characters com literally (case sensitive)
>
> ? /? matches the character / literally (case sensitive)
>
> ? Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
>   ? \? matches the character ? literally (case sensitive)
>
> Global pattern flags
>
> g modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match)
>   m modifier: multi line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I'm after.